# Facebook Ads API how to get all campaigns that are in draft status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-java-api

I have created a Ads and campaigns in Facebook Ads Manager. But they are not yet published

I have tried the following API call to get a list of all the campaigns I have created,

```
/v3.2/act_XXXX/campaigns
```

But I am getting an empty response,

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Is there any other way to list all the campaigns created irrespective of they are published or not

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? The suggestion below doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access all draft campaigns with the Facebook marketing API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058289/how-to-access-all-draft-campaigns-with-the-facebook-marketing-api)

Answer (score 0):

The default filter is ACTIVE campaign, if you want to retrieve for different state you can use the filter options, as example:

```
act_XXXX/campaigns?filtering=[{'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':["ACTIVE","PAUSED","PENDING_REVIEW"]}]&fields=name,effective_status
```

And add in the list the status you need, from the doc:

> effective_status enum {ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, PENDING_REVIEW,
>   DISAPPROVED, PREAPPROVED, PENDING_BILLING_INFO, CAMPAIGN_PAUSED,
>   ARCHIVED, ADSET_PAUSED, WITH_ISSUES}

[Facebook doc here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/)

Comment: I am still getting an empty response after using the above given parameters

Comment: hi @r123 have tried using ALL the possible state listed in the answer? Are you able to use the campaign id in order to retrieve it and check for the status?

Comment: yes, I have tried all possible states. Also, I am not able to use the campaign id in order to retrieve it

Comment: I think there is a difference between the ```effective_status``` variable and whether a campaign is in draft or published mode. I also struggle to retrieve draft campaigns.

Comment: @TeaTree try filtering by `status` instead of `effective_status`

Comment: I don't think that'll work: from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group), ```configured_status```  takes one of these values: ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, ARCHIVED. ```effective_status``` takes ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, ARCHIVED, IN_PROCESS, WITH_ISSUES. ```status``` takes ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, ARCHIVED. The draft status of a campaign is different though and not listed anywhere here.