# How to access all draft campaigns with the Facebook marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to list all of my draft campaigns using the Facebook marketing API. By default, it seems, only non-draft (published?) campaigns are listed when calling

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/act_12345/campaigns?fields=id,name&access_token=<mytoken>"
```

When looking at the code of the [facebook-python-business-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/search?q=UnpublishedContentType), there are multiple references to unpublished content type, which makes me think that there should be a way to list all unpublished campaigns. So my question is how can I list all campaigns, published and unpublished?

I know this question is a duplicate (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758545/facebook-graph-api-not-showing-draft-campaign), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109211/facebook-marketing-api-cant-get-draft-campaigns-ads-and-adsets), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157095/facebook-ads-api-how-to-get-all-campaigns-that-are-in-draft-status)) but I'm asking it again since it has not been answered and I'd like to put out a bounty for a helpful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to get draft campaigns is below:

1. You should get all `addrafts`. On my account I have only 1 addraft that contains all draft campaigns, but maybe you can have more. URL for getting `addrafts`:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/act_<ad_account_id>/addrafts?access_token=<access_token>&fields=name,ad_object_id,id`

2. Now you can get `addraft_fragments`. You can see all draft fragments of your ad_account (campaigns, adsets, ads), but you can easily find here what you want. URL for getting `addraft_fragments`:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/<addraft_id>/addraft_fragments?access_token=<access_token>&fields=name,id,ad_object_id,ad_object_type,budget,ad_object_name,values`

Comment: When running the first call, I receive ```"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (addrafts) on node type (AdAccount)",```

Comment: @TeaTree what type of access_token do you use? I suppose you use access_token of developer application, this token doesn't have needed permissions. But user access_token used on Facebook Ads Manager user interfaces have this permissions.

Comment: Interesting, I was under the impression that I would always have to create a Facebook App in order to use the Marketing API. How do I get a Ads Manager access_token?

Comment: There is no documented way to get this token. The only way is to get it from page source code at Facebook UI, for example at Ads Manager.